# Dataframe (5mb) consuming all the available ram, system crashing

Tags: python, pandas

Ive got this dataframe

```
sal.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 127606 entries, 0 to 127605
Data columns (total 6 columns):
id     127606 non-null int64
start    127606 non-null object
end      127606 non-null object
cc             127606 non-null float64
ep             58505 non-null float64
ip             58465 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 5.8+ MB
```

At this moment, I have got 5 out of 8 GB ram as free, but as soon as I run

```
sal.iloc[1]
```

It consumes my entire memory and system crashes all the time.
 I dont know why its happening, as Ive worked with df's 4 times the size of this one with ease. Its not even printing the first row !!

If Im lucky the kernel interrupt works (else it freezes and reboot is required).
Then I do a gc :-

```
import gc
gc.collect()
out : 4297
```

Guys any idea whats happening and how to solve this ?

Im on Anaconda jupyter notebook, version 1.7, 64bit, python 3

Comment: `start` and `end` are objects. Is that right? Shouldn't they be a datetime dtype?

Comment: Yeah but it shudnt make it consume all the RAM up